# Scatterplot on top of line plot ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Example data:

```
set.seed(245)
cond <- rep( c("control","treatment"), each=10)
xval <- round(10+ rnorm(20), 1)
yval <- round(10+ rnorm(20), 1)
df <- data.frame(cond, xval, yval)
df$xval[cond=="treatment"] <- df$xval[cond=="treatment"] + 1.5
```

I would like the "treatment" condition be plotted as a line and the "control" data be plotted as a scatter plot. So far, I have found a work around where I specify them to both be lines but chose that the control line be plotted as 'blank' in scale_linetype_manual:

```
plot <-ggplot(data=df, aes(x=xval, y=yval, group=cond, colour=cond))+
geom_line(aes(linetype=cond))+
geom_point(aes(shape=cond))+
scale_linetype_manual(values=c('blank', 'solid'))
```

However, there must be a more straightforward way of plotting the control as a scatter plot and the treatment as a line plot. Eventually, I'd like to remove the geom_point from the treatment line. The way it is now, it would remove the its from the control as well leaving me with nothing for the control.

Any insight would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I have understood you correctly. You may use a "treatment" `subset` of the data for `geom_line`, and a "control" `subset` for `geom_point`.

After the subsetting, there is only one "cond" for `geom_line` ("treatment") and one for `geom_point` ("control"). Thus, I have removed the `aes` **mapping** between "cond" and `colour`, `linetype` and `shape` respectively. You may wish to **set** these aesthetics to desired values instead. Similarly, no need for `group` in this solution.

```
ggplot(data = subset(df, cond == "treatment"), aes(x = xval, y = yval)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(data = subset(df, cond == "control"))
```

[image]

**Update** following comment from OP, "Now, what if my data had actually three "conditions" where 2 of the conditions would be plotted as lines and the other 1 is scatterplot."

```
# some data
set.seed(123)
cond <- rep( c("contr","treat", "post-treat"), each = 10)
xval <- rnorm(30)
yval <- rnorm(30)
df <- data.frame(cond, xval, yval)

# plot
ggplot(data = subset(df, cond %in% c("treat", "post-treat")), aes(x = xval, y = yval)) +
         geom_line(aes(group = cond, colour = cond)) +
         geom_point(data = subset(df, cond == "contr"))
```

[image]

Comment: this is the same solution I was working on!  but I think the OP's solution is excellent as it is, in fact.  I like that it is easy to map colour and shape to `cond` in her approach

Comment: @AndrewMacDonald, That's the part (i.e. map colour and shape) I am a bit unsure of. There is only one "cond" for the `geom_line` and one for the `geom_point`. Thus, I didn't quite see the point of **mapping** "cond", and would rather **set** them. But I might be wrong..;)

Comment: @Henrik, thanks for the solution. Now, what if my data had actually three "conditions" where 2 of the conditions would be plotted as lines and the other 1 is scatterplot. I'm thinking that I might just add it in e.g.:

Comment: whoops- hit enter too soon,   (...cond== "treatment" & == "post-treatment"), aes ..... )

Comment: @Elizabeth, in that case I would try `ggplot(data = subset(df, cond %in% c("treatment", "post-treatment"), aes(x = xval, y = yval)) + geom_line(aes(group = cond, colour = cond))`.

Comment: @Henrik, hmm doesn't seem to do the trick.. Appreciate your help, though!

Comment: @Henrik, Yes! Very much so. Thanks for your thought! I up-graded your answer and approved.